# Does react-native AsyncStorage persist between playstore updates?

Tags: react-native

I can't find anything about this.

I need a way to persist data between app updates on the play store and I'm not sure if the AsyncStorage does the job.
I assume it does, since on every build I perform, the data is there.

But I'm not sure about different versioning in the store.
If it doesn't, how could I handle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the AsyncStorage keeps the data between updates like if you had had a database. For Android, AsyncStorage data is stored in a database that is linked to your package id and doesn't get deleted unless the app is uninstalled. AsyncStorage should be enough for you. From RN docs:

> On iOS, AsyncStorage is backed by native code that stores small values
>   in a serialized dictionary and larger values in separate files. On
>   Android, AsyncStorage will use either RocksDB or SQLite based on what
>   is available.

Comment: My problem was if it was linked through the app version or something like it. But this part answered all my questions: "is linked to your package id". Thank you

Comment: I tried to clear data for the application from application manager and found the AsyncStorage data was also deleted. Is there any way to prevent it?