# React-Native AsyncStorage state lost after update

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, asyncstorage

After I issued an update via Google Play Store I noticed that all users had to go through onboarding and login again.

Since I store the fact that a user went through onboarding in react-natives's `AsyncStorage` I think the reason is that the state is not persisted between updates.

The code I use is something along the line of:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (!value) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(storageKey, 'pending');
   }
} catch (err) {}
```

Later I set the state to 'done'. I use aws-amplify for authentication, which stores a logged in user into AsyncStroage as well (afik). This state is lost as well.

In the React-Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) it says that AsyncStorage is persistend.

My question is: How do I get persistent state between updates across platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't persist through updates, as you're downloading and installing new binaries. You might have to have an API call as a fallback if `value` is undefined.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. It says that it should here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065773/11034665